# Finding Dates of different format in text with javascript

Tags: javascript

I've a bunch of paragraph, which have dates in it in different format. for Example: 
American soldiers in combat at the Battle of Long Island, 1 May, 1776
After regrouping at Halifax, William Howe determined to take the fight to the Americans.[139] He set sail in 5 June 1776 and began landing troops on Staten Island near the entrance to New York Harbor on July 2 1949. Due to poor military intelligence, Washington split his army to positions on Manhattan Island and across the East River in western Long Island,[140] and an informal attempt to negotiate peace was rejected by the Americans.[141] On 06 August 27, Howe outflanked Washington and forced him back to Brooklyn Heights 02-03-2019. Howe restrained 01/02/2012 his subordinates from pursuit, opting to besiege 02/03/2014  Washington instead.[142]

In the example paragraph, there are some dates like

1 May, 1776

5 June 1776

July 2 1949

01/02/2012

02/03/2014

02-03-2019

I need to extract those dates from this paragraph. I found that There's a python package doing something like this : [datefinder](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder)
hope anyone can help me there a bit, or please tell is there any other way achieve it.
Thanks in advace

Comment: You're either asking us to find an existing library, or to write one for you. Neither of which is on-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: pardon me please if it's anyway break the rules of stackoverflow. since i'm just asking the way I should go. @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: why don't you look into the source code of that python package to get an idea. And then post your attempt here and let us know where you're stuck, if it doesen't work.

Comment: @jps I dont know python yet, by the way, the problem is solved. I appreciate all of your kind regards. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this.

It is not optimal and may detect non-date string / not detect a date

but It works with the example you've given

```js
let text = "I've a bunch of paragraph, which have dates in it in different format. for Example: American soldiers in combat at the Battle of Long Island, 1 May, 1776 After regrouping at Halifax, William Howe determined to take the fight to the Americans.[139] He set sail in 5 June 1776 and began landing troops on Staten Island near the entrance to New York Harbor on July 2 1949. Due to poor military intelligence, Washington split his army to positions on Manhattan Island and across the East River in western Long Island,[140] and an informal attempt to negotiate peace was rejected by the Americans.[141] On 06 August 27, Howe outflanked Washington and forced him back to Brooklyn Heights 02-03-2019. Howe restrained 01/02/2012 his subordinates from pursuit, opting to besiege 02/03/2014 Washington instead.[142] test 2 1254"

let dates = [];

let words = text.split(" ")

// these char if left in string cannot be send to date
// Maybe you'll need to add some as you enconter them
let forbiddenChar = /[.]/g

// for each word
for (let i in words) {
  // if it contains 4 consecutive number (something looking like a year)
  if (words[i].match(/.*[0-9]{4}.*/)) {
    // if the "year" is not at the start (full date)
    if (words[i].search(/[0-9]{4}/) !== 0) {
      words[i] = words[i].replace(/[-]/g, "/").replace(forbiddenChar, " ");
      
      let date = new Date(words[i])
        
      if (date.toString() != "Invalid Date") {
        dates.push(date)
      }
    // the "year" is at the start of word
    } else {
      if (i >= 2) {
        // the other part of the date appear before the year
        let date = `${words[i - 2]} ${words[i - 1]} ${words[i]}` 
        date = new Date(date.replace(forbiddenChar, " "))
        
        if (date.toString() != "Invalid Date") {
          dates.push(date)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(dates)
```